# How to set background image to an ClientBundle resource in uibinder (GWT)

Tags: url, gwt, uibinder

How to set background image in uibinder/java to an image in ClientBundle without using:

```
obj.getElement().getStyle().setBackgroundImage("url("+Images.INSTANCE.bg().getURL()+")");
```

Because this doesn't work in IE (FF is OK).
I think I should set the background image directly in uibinder with css @url or ...

(I am using GWT 2.0.3)
Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [docs](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideClientBundle.html#Image_Sprites) explain this :) (note that internally UiBinder uses `CssResource`, so all that applies to `CssResource`, applies to the CSS styles you define in UiBinder's `<ui:style>` too)

Answer (score 0):

ImageResource uses Data Urls and spriting. Sadly, older versions of IE support neither of these well. Data Url is not supported at all and on i.e. 7- a new copy of the entire sprite image is used for every clipped appearance of the image. So, if you have a sprite with 100 icons and use it in 100 places, IE will consume the memory of 100x that image.

Try to get away from really old IE if you can.